# Extracting the coefficient of a certain term from a polynomial

Tags: coefficients

I want to take out the coefficient of `z1^a1 z2^a2 ... zn^an` from a polynomial function `expr`,where `a1,a2,...,an` can be positive, negative, or zero.Then, I use n `Coefficient` functions,

```
Coefficient[...[Coefficient[Coefficient[expr,z1,a1],z2,a2],...],zn,an]
```

However, there are too many `Coefficient` functions. Is there a simpler method

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include a minimal example that can be copied, pasted and studied in order to suggest solutions. Thanks.

Comment: the denominator contains ```z1 z2``` , why it does not have ```z1^(-1) z2^(-1)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

factorzrminus1[
  r_] := -(((-4 + d + 2 r) (m1^2 - m2^2 + z1 - z2 + dot[q1, q1] - 
        2 dot[q1, q2] + dot[q2, q2]) (dot[q1, R] - dot[q2, R]))/(4 z1 z2))

a1[r_] := Coefficient[Coefficient[factorzrminus1[r], z1, -1], z2, -1]
```

Use [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) for multiple variables

```
a2[r_] := Fold[Coefficient[##, -1] &, factorzrminus1[r], {z1, z2}]
```

Verifying that the results are identical,

```
a1[r] === a2[r]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** for arbitrary exponents

```
a1[expr_, arr_?ArrayQ] := Fold[Coefficient[#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, expr, arr]

a1[r] === a1[factorzrminus1[r], {{z1, -1}, {z2, -1}}]

(* True *)

a1[factorzrminus1[r], {{z1, -1}, {z2, 0}}]

(* 1/4 (-4 + d + 2 r) (dot[q1, R] - dot[q2, R]) *)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a general method, as it doesn't work for cases such as ```z1^-1  z2^0```. And if ```factorzrminus1[r]``` has 4 variables(```z1 z2 z3 z4```),  how to get the factor of ```z1^a1  z2^a2 z3^a3  z4^a4``` .

Comment: If you want a more general solution, then `a1` must have more arguments than just `r`. Show what you expect as input and output. It is not up to us to guess what you want.